# Mass assignment for elements in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm dealing with pulling in information from an API and want to take that data and inserting it into certain elements of different classes within a `for-loop`. Right now I'm doing this through a `switch-statement` wrapped inside an `.each()` method. It just seems that this way for one is repetitive and probably is more performance heavy than anything. Is there a way to accomplish this in a more concise and efficient way?

```js
var tracks = [{number: "01", title: "Track 1", duration: "5:35"}, {number: "02", title: "Track 2", duration: "5:15"}, {number: "03", title: "Track 3", duration: "5:07"}, {number: "04", title: "Track 4", duration: "0:16"}, {number: "05", title: "Track 5", duration: "5:35"}];

for (var i = 0, trackNumber, trackTitle, trackDuration; i < tracks.length; i++) {
  trackNumber   = tracks[i]["number"];
  trackTitle    = tracks[i]["title"];
  trackDuration = tracks[i]["duration"];
  
  $("span").each(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("class")) {
      case "number":
        $(".number").eq(i).text(trackNumber);
      case "title":
        $(".title").eq(i).text(trackTitle);
      case "duration":
        $(".duration").eq(i).text(trackDuration);
      default:
        //
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><b>No</b></td>
      <td><b>Title</b></td>
      <td><b>Duration</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="number"></span></td>
    <td><span class="title"></span></td>
    <td><span class="duration"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="number"></span></td>
    <td><span class="title"></span></td>
    <td><span class="duration"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="number"></span></td>
    <td><span class="title"></span></td>
    <td><span class="duration"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="number"></span></td>
    <td><span class="title"></span></td>
    <td><span class="duration"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="number"></span></td>
    <td><span class="title"></span></td>
    <td><span class="duration"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you generate the elements dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could code:

```
$('tbody td span').text(function() {
    var i = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1;
    return tracks[i][this.className];
});
```

In the above snippet `rowIndex` of the `tr` elements is used for getting a specific array's element by index. Using bracket notation (`[index]`) and the `className` of the `span` element the corresponding property's value is set by the `text` method. [Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/f7wdr6va/)

As the table has one 1 row in the `thead` element the `rowIndex` of the first `tr` child of the `tbody` element is `1`. That's why the returned value is subtracted by 1.

As a note, you should consider generating the `tr` elements according to the returned data. Using a templating library can be an option.

**edit**: You could also use vanilla JavaScript:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('tbody td span');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function (el) {
    var i = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1;
    el.textContent = tracks[i][el.className];
});
```

Comment: The one thing I'm still confused about is subtracting 1 from the `rowIndex`. Why is that?

Comment: Thanks this looks great. Two additional questions if you don't mind. Hypothetically speaking if I were to use this snippet in a different project where the span had no parents would the `parentNode` or `rowInded` be needed? The second question, performance wise, would the `.text()` method suffice as opposed to the `for-loop`?

Comment: @CarlEdwards You are welcome. Only `tr` elements have `rowIndex` property,  `td` elements have `cellIndex` which works like the `rowIndex`. Many DOM elements do not have corresponding properties. You can use jQuery `.index()` method whenever you need indices. The above snippet uses `rowIndex`  for making the code more efficient. And the above code should work much faster than your current code. You can test the snippets on http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Many thanks once again. +1 for helping reduce 18 lines to 4 in such a clear and concise manner.

Comment: @CarlEdwards You are very welcome! I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Can I ask just one last question (my apologies in advance if it slightly deviates from the scope of the question). In the event where the name of the object's key differs from the class of the span what would be the best approach to target that particular key?

Comment: @CarlEdwards No problem. In that case an `undefined` value is returned. You can use `data-*` attributes. Something like `data-prop='track-number'`, then in your code instead of the `this.className` you can use `this.getAttribute('data-prop')`.

Comment: Okay so say for instance I had the class name like you mentioned previously `track-number` and one of the keys of the `tracks` object has the name of `trackNumber` the data attribute would match them up?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Well, those are 2 different strings. So, the answer is no. If the keys are "camelCased" and you are using "hyphenated-compounds" classNames you have to convert the case at first. The point of `data-*` attributes was using the exact keys as values. This way modifying the classNames doesn't break the script.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use:

```
 $("span.number").eq(i).text(trackNumber);
 $("span.title").eq(i).text(trackTitle);
 $("span.duration").eq(i).text(trackDuration);
```

Comment: Bam. Why make complicated :)

Comment: Note: it wil be much better to cache `$("span.number")` and two others before the loop.

Comment: Is your code still considered DRY by doing it this way? I'm putting it into perspective where the hash may have 5-10 properties that need to be inserted.

Comment: yes it is. also use the suggestion given by regent.

Comment: Good to know thanks. Going back to my original code I wonder. Does having and `.each()` method inside a `for-loop` redundant in any situation?

Comment: indeed it is redundant for the purpose you are using.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var attr = $(this).attr("class");
$("." + attr).eq(i).text(tracks[i][attr]);
```

Comment: What would `$(this)` be referring to?

Comment: I'm assuming in the body of the `.each()` method?

Comment: that's right. i assumed you would like to assign values without the switch