# Assigning values to specific inputs from a hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash, key-value

Right now I'm working with the iTunes search API and trying to extract data from the key/value pairs of an album's tracklist and insert them into specific text inputs. I was able to accomplish [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628285/mass-assignment-for-elements-in-a-for-loop) inside a table but due to how the app is currently setup it now calls for inputs to be nested inside a pair of divs.

The value assignments work where the object's key name matches up to the data name attribute and insert's that particular value. The object's pairs are iterated through the index of the input in the `.track-form` div. The iterator seems to stop short at the second key/value for some reason though. Instead it should fill in the row inputs in the order of the `tracks` object.

```js
var tracks = [
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "01", trackName: "Track 01"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "02", trackName: "Track 02"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "03", trackName: "Track 03"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "04", trackName: "Track 04"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "05", trackName: "Track 05"}
];

$('.track-form').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.track-input').val(function(i) {
    var dataName        = $(this).data("name"),
        camelCasedClass = toCamelCase(dataName);
    return tracks[i][camelCasedClass];
  });
  
  function toCamelCase(name) {
      var camelCase = name.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function(g) {
        return g[1].toUpperCase();
      });

      return camelCase;
  }
});
```

```css
.track-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.track-form:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got your "i" in the wrong function - it's always returning as 0 because it's the first input in the container.  Try this:

```js
var tracks = [
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "01", trackName: "Track 01"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "02", trackName: "Track 02"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "03", trackName: "Track 03"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "04", trackName: "Track 04"}, 
  {discNumber: "01", trackNumber: "05", trackName: "Track 05"}
];

$('.track-form').each(function(i) {

  $(this).find('.track-input').val(function() {
    var dataName        = $(this).data("name"),
        camelCasedClass = toCamelCase(dataName);
    return tracks[i][camelCasedClass];
  });
  
  function toCamelCase(name) {
      var camelCase = name.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function(g) {
        return g[1].toUpperCase();
      });

      return camelCase;
  }
});
```

```css
.track-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.track-form:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="track-form">
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="discNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="track-container">
    <input type="text" class="track-input" data-name="trackName" />
  </div>
</div>
```